# Total Memory displayed using psutil is very different from what is displayed using linux free command

Tags: python, psutil

i have 16 GB ram on my system. when i call `psutil.virtual_memory()` i get the following output:

```
svmem: svmem(total=16645505024, available=11897528320, percent=28.5, used=3655700480, free=9460736000, active=4557766656, inactive=1540661248, buffers=192524288, cached=3336544256, shared=765763584, slab=259469312)
```

When i use free command in linux i get the following output:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16255376     3932008     8559892     1012532     3763476    10989204
Swap:       7910396           0     7910396
```

Output from `/proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:       16255096 kB
MemFree:         7364100 kB
MemAvailable:   10076292 kB
Buffers:          174508 kB
Cached:          4166520 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          5124828 kB
Inactive:        2277680 kB
Active(anon):    4022420 kB
Inactive(anon):   494860 kB
Active(file):    1102408 kB
Inactive(file):  1782820 kB
Unevictable:      951160 kB
Mlocked:              80 kB
SwapTotal:       7910396 kB
SwapFree:        7910396 kB
Dirty:               432 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       4012684 kB
Mapped:          1452264 kB
Shmem:           1461568 kB
KReclaimable:     165196 kB
Slab:             292904 kB
SReclaimable:     165196 kB
SUnreclaim:       127708 kB
KernelStack:       37312 kB
PageTables:       126352 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    16037944 kB
Committed_AS:   22750636 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       56604 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             6016 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      379288 kB
DirectMap2M:    12062720 kB
DirectMap1G:     5242880 kB
```

The main issue here is that psutil data in bytes translated to more than 16GB of memory. That cannot be true of course.My expectation is to get a value that will tell me i have 16 GB ram. Vallue cannot cross the actual value can it?

I understand that `free` output is in kb while psutils is bytes but by no means can i see parity in them. why are the values so off?

Comment: If you read the source to the psutil library, you'll see which specific procfs interface it's checking. That's really the most efficient way to get a guaranteed-correct answer here -- otherwise, you're just asking someone else to read the source for you (which is what writing an answer is going to come down to).

Comment: That said, it would be helpful if you described what you _expect_ the relationship between the numbers to be. We can't tell you why you aren't getting what you think you'll see if you don't tell us what you think you'll see.

Comment: (Also, could you please provide a dump of `/proc/meminfo` from the same machine -- and at the same time -- where the other values are collected, and tell us which version of `ps` you have installed?)

Comment: ...if you want to [edit] just one thing into your question, consider something like the output of `set -x; ps --version; cat /proc/meminfo; free; python -c 'import psutil; print(repr(psutil.virtual_memory()))'` -- running that all at once as a single one-line command reduces the amount of variance over time between samples.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i updated the question with the info you requested.

Comment: Accounting for the difference between base-2 and base-10, those numbers look pretty close.

Comment: "Available" isn't all that close, but you didn't answer my question about what version of `free` you have, and how `free`'s copy is calculated is version-dependent.

Comment: ...what part of the output from psutil, _specifically_, makes you think it's showing more than 16gb of RAM? `$((16645505024 / 1024 / 1024))` comes out to `15874`, which is less than 16gb.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok i think i got my mistake on this one. i used 1000 instead of 1024 that gave me variance. if i use `free -m` i get `15874`.  Version is `free from procps-ng 3.3.12`